# Remove commas between tags

Tags: tags

So I have been googling for quite some time now and I can't seem to solve this. A lot of sources refer to a file called `the_tags.php` but it's nowhere to be found. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a php file, it's a core function: [`the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags).

```
<?php
$before = '';
$seperator = ''; // blank instead of comma
$after = '';

the_tags( $before, $seperator, $after );
?>
```

Comment: So where do I put this? I can't find the code anywhere in a template, so I suppose it goes in functions?

Comment: this would go in your template in the loop, but adding this will just output another set of tags. you need to find where your template is outputting tags and edit that function.

Comment: I'm using a child theme of twentyeleven, and still I can find no mention of "tags" anywhere!

Comment: twentyeleven uses [`get_the_tag_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list)

Comment: Thanks for the find. I replaced every single comma that was in a $sep variable by a space, and it's fixed now. Thanks again!